# Which is android's texture coordinate and how is the texture mapped?

Tags: android, textures, texture-mapping

I am confused when I do texture mapping.

Which texture coordinate does android use and how is the texture mapped?

Here are two definitions of texture coordinate I found. Which one is correct?

[image: first definition]

[image: second definition]

Comment: They are same, just vertical axis opposite. Each texture vertex corresponds polygon vertex.

Comment: Perhaps he is asking which way is the source image (bmp/png/jpg) interpreted, say, by a texture creation/compression tool? <shrug>